Maximum a Posteriori (MAP) in practice for machine learning
I'm a beginner in machine learning and I had a a few questions regarding MAP.
From my limited understanding it seems to me a bayesian approach, specifically an MLE approach is incredibly useful when constructing loss functions for a machine learning model – negative log, cross entropy, elbo, etc.

I was wondering if there are any practical examples where MAP was used to construct a loss function. The only example I can find are the L1 and L2 regularizations, where L1 regularization term can be derived from a laplacean prior, and L2 regularization term can be derived from a guassian prior.

On an intuitive level what does it mean when a prior has a guassian or laplacean distribution? Is it unlikely for a prior to have, for instance, and exponential distribution?

Do other regularization techniques such as dropout and batch normalization have MAP interpretations like the L1 and L2 regularizations? From my understanding, dropout and batch normalization don't affect the loss function so I'm guessing that's not the case.



Not an answer to your questions, but perhaps you benefit from having a peek at my tutorial. You can read most of it online under "Read Sample."  https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0BTNVFR65

@RomkeBontekoe Thank you! I was looking for something like this.
